# Conditional logic when grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to group some records in a SQL Server 2014 table by using some conditional logic based on multiple fields and I am not sure how to do it. I have created a contrived example to explain what I am looking for as far as results.

Here is a table of Patient Procedures:

```
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| Id |  Name | Insurance | ProcedureName | ProcedureDate |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  1 |  Bob  |  Medicaid |   Blood Test  |   2017-06-01  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  2 |  Bob  |  Medicaid |   Urinalysis  |   2017-06-03  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  3 |  Bob  |  Self Pay |  Liver Biopsy |   2017-05-02  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  4 |  Bob  |  Self Pay |    CAT Scan   |   2017-05-07  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  5 | Sally |  Medicaid |   Ultrasound  |   2017-07-07  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  6 | Sally |  Medicaid |     X-Ray     |   2017-07-12  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  7 | Sally |  Medicaid |   Blood Test  |   2017-08-10  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I would like to group these records by name such that I only end up with two records. One for Bob and one for Sally. Since the fields **Insurance**, **ProcedureName**, and **ProcedureDate** hold different values I realize that I need to decide which values to use for these fields in the grouping. Here are the rules:

1. If the Insurance is anything other than Medicaid use the data from the Non-Medicaid record with the most recent ProcedureDate.
2. If the insurance is all Medicaid then use the data from the row with the most recent ProcedureDate.

So I would want to end up with the following two records:

```
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| Id |  Name | Insurance | ProcedureName | ProcedureDate |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  4 |  Bob  |  Self Pay |  Liver Biopsy |   2017-05-02  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  7 | Sally |  Medicaid |   Blood Test  |   2017-08-10  |
+----+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I created a [sample SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e59b9/1) for this question. How do I go about using conditional logic in the GROUP BY clause to get the answer I want?

Comment: the expected result doesn't match criteria 1 for Bob.

Comment: @Vamsi - Thanks! I spent so much time setting it up I got the data incorrect. I fixed the results.

Comment: in both rules , you need data from the record with the most recent date ??

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: @Marian - Yes, the requirements are such that I need to prioritize one record over another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a prioritization query. Use a `case` expression in `order by` of `row_number` with the criteria mentioned.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from tbl 
order by row_number() over(partition by name order by 
                           case when insurance<>'Medicaid' then 1 else 2 end,
                           proceduredate desc)
```

Comment: I checked the SQL in Sql Fiddle and it works. Just had to change `tbl` to `PatientProcedure`

Answer (score 1):

I put together this poor solution. It can not compare with the Vamsi Prabhala solution, however, I believe that it is correct so I post it here.

```
select p1.*
from PatientProcedure p1
left join (select p2.name, max(p2.ProcedureDate) m from PatientProcedure p2 group by p2.name) t1 on t1.name = p1.name
left join (select p2.name, max(p2.ProcedureDate) m, count(p2.ProcedureDate) ct from PatientProcedure p2 where p2.insurance != 'Medicaid' group by p2.name) t2 on t2.name = p1.name
where 
(
  t2.ct is null and
  ProcedureDate = t1.m
) or
(
  insurance != 'Medicaid' and 
  ProcedureDate = t2.m
)
```

I believe that these two `LEFT JOIN`s can be grouped as well, however, maybe next time :)